# Genetic variation in humans and model organisms (measured by SNPs)

Tags: snp

I was wondering what is the range of SNP density across species and model organisms.

I.e., what would be a reasonable estimate for the SNP density (i.e., x SNPs for each 1 Kb) in:

1. humans
2. humans with the highest variation (i.e., Africans)
3. flies
4. mouse
5. lab mice with highest variation (i.e., isogenic lab mouse 1 with isogenic lab mouse 2 with the highest variation)
6. model organism with the highest snp density (could be lab or naturally occurring)

Answer (score 1):

### **SNP Density**

**Human = ~1.18 SNPs per kbases**

> Based on CgsSNP, the average numbers of SNPs per 10 kb was 8.33, 8.44,
>   and 8.09 in the human genome, in intergenic regions, and in genic
>   regions, respectively.

Source: [*Investigating single nucleotide polymorphism (SNP) density in the human genome and its implications for molecular evolution.* by Zhao Z, Fu YX, Hewett-Emmett D, Boerwinkle E.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12909357)

***Drosophila melanogaster* = ~0.02 SNP per kbases**

> FLYSNPdb provides high-resolution single nucleotide polymorphism (SNP)
>   data of Drosophila melanogaster. The database currently contains 27
>   367 polymorphisms, including >3700 indels (insertions/deletions),
>   covering all major chromsomes. These SNPs are clustered into 2238
>   markers, which are evenly distributed with an average density of one
>   marker every 50.3 kb or 6.6 genes.

source: [FLYSNPdb: a high-density SNP database of Drosophila melanogaster](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/37/suppl_1/D567.long)

**Mouse(*Mus musculus*) = ~0.2 SNP per kbases**

Source: [Genome-wide single-nucleotide polymorphism
analysis defines haplotype patterns in mouse](http://www.pnas.org/content/100/6/3380.full.pdf)